# Proof that $n!+n!<(n-k)!+(n+k)!$

Tags: combinatorics

So I have got a question that I am stuck for a few days:

> Proof that $n!+n!<(n-k)!+(n+k)!$ for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\leq n$.

**My attempt:** We perform induction on $n$.

Base case: $n=1$
The only case is when $k=1$. We have $n!+n!=2$ and $(n-k)!+(n+k)!=3$.

Assume that it is true for some $n$. Then $2n!<(n-k)!+(n+k)!$ for all $k$. We have $2(n+1)!=n(2n!)<n(n-k)!+n(n+k)!$.

But then I don't know what to do. I don't even know if induction is a right approach. Can someone please help? Thanks so much.

Comment: A word of caution: Some conventions have $0\in\mathbb{N}$, and the (strict) inequality is not true if $k=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, consider
$$ n! + n! = 2 \cdot n!$$
while
$$ (n-k)! + (n+k)! > (n+k)! > (n+1)! = n! (n+1).$$
The first inequality is true as long as $n \geq k$ (so that both factorials are defined). The second inequality is true as long as $k \geq 1$ (if $k = 0$, then both sides in the original problem are clearly equal).

Then as $2 \cdot n! \leq (n+1) \cdot n!$ for $n \geq 1$, we have
$$ n! + n! \leq (n+1) n! < (n+k)! < (n-k)! + (n+k)!$$

Answer (score 0):

if $k$ is increased by 1, then RHS changes by

$$-(n-k-1)(n-k-1)!+(n+k)(n+k)!$$

which is positive for $k\ge{}0$. Thus, if the claim is true for $k$ then it is true for $k+1$.

So we just need to prove the claim for $k=1$ which is easy:

$$n+n\le{}n^2+n<1+(n+1)n$$

Multiply by $(n-1)!$ and you get the result.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks, edited.